# Invalid signature error while booting Windows 8

Tags: grub2, windows-8

I am new to Ubuntu and I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 so it works perfectly.
But after I enter on Windows 8 it shows this: `ERROR: INVALID SIGNATURE` 
what should I do to get my Windows back?

Answer (score 0):

What would certainly help is to use  [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) so we can get a precise idea on what's going on.
Then I assume you try to get to win8 trough grub.

What could have happened is:

-you installed 32bit ubuntu (and messed up legacy and uefi).

-you simply erased the windows partition (install Gparted so we might see it)

I hope this might eventually help